# Linear PCM 16 bit to 8 bit

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, audio, audioqueue

I am trying to adopt recording part of the Apple example entitled "SpeakHere" to my purposes. Everything seems to fine, but I need to add an option which actually offers 8 bit recording.
This is according to the specification not allowed by any audio settings, so I need some kind of conversion from 16 bit.
I think I need to place it in the callback function.

```
// ____________________________________________________________________________________
// AudioQueue callback function, called when an input buffers has been filled.
void AQRecorder::MyInputBufferHandler(  void *                              inUserData,
                                        AudioQueueRef                       inAQ,
                                        AudioQueueBufferRef                 inBuffer,
                                        const AudioTimeStamp *              inStartTime,
                                        UInt32                              inNumPackets,
                                        const AudioStreamPacketDescription* inPacketDesc)
{
    AQRecorder *aqr = (AQRecorder *)inUserData;
    try {
        if (inNumPackets > 0) {
            // write packets to file
            XThrowIfError(AudioFileWritePackets(aqr->mRecordFile, FALSE, inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize,
                                             inPacketDesc, aqr->mRecordPacket, &inNumPackets, inBuffer->mAudioData),
                       "AudioFileWritePackets failed");
            aqr->mRecordPacket += inNumPackets;
        }

        // if we're not stopping, re-enqueue the buffe so that it gets filled again
        if (aqr->IsRunning())
            XThrowIfError(AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(inAQ, inBuffer, 0, NULL), "AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer failed");
    } catch (CAXException e) {
        char buf[256];
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s (%s)\n", e.mOperation, e.FormatError(buf));
    }
}
```

but to be honest don't know how. Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you just need to divide each sample by 256. I'm not familiar with the abstractions and data structures used in your sample, but if you can get to the raw PCM data, you just treat each two bytes as a `signed short int` and divide each one by 256 and write into a buffer of `signed char`s. Of course, you still have to create the correct metadata to indicate that your data is 8-bit per sample PCM audio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite of investigation and trying things, I have found out, that I do not need conversion, but just have to set different format flags.

```
mRecordFormat.mFormatFlags      = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsBigEndian;
mRecordFormat.mBitsPerChannel   = 8;
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try to initialize your audio queue with something like that ?

```
    aqData.mDataFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;        // 2
    aqData.mDataFormat.mSampleRate = 44100.0;                    // 3
    aqData.mDataFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;                    // 4
    aqData.mDataFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 8;                     // 5
    aqData.mDataFormat.mBytesPerPacket =                         // 6
    aqData.mDataFormat.mBytesPerFrame =
    aqData.mDataFormat.mChannelsPerFrame * sizeof (SInt8);
    aqData.mDataFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;                     // 7

    AudioFileTypeID fileType = kAudioFileAIFFType;               // 8
    aqData.mDataFormat.mFormatFlags =                            // 9
    kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsBigEndian
    | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger
    | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked;
```

Comment: The following variations of linear PCM audio should be supported by all CAF parsers:

Any sample rate
Samples of 16-, 24-, and 32-bit signed integer, both big- and little-endian
Samples of 32- and 64-bit floating point, both big- and little-endian